# Excel solver failure to get optimal solution when generating a schedule for 12 week schedule for 24 teams

Tags: excel, linear-programming, solver, mixed-integer-programming, excel-solver

I've been tasked with generating a schedule with 24 unique teams.

Rules:

- Over the 11 weeks each team plays 2 matchups
- In week 12 each team plays a single matchup
- The result is every team plays every other team exactly once

Problem setup
[image: Excel Solver Problem Setup]

**Constraints**:

- a 24x24 matrix of cells are the input variables for the problem. Each value must be a week between 0 and 12.  0 is used to block out the cell to avoid scheduling a team against itself.
- Each row needs to add up to 144 (0+1+2+...12)
- On the far right 0 must be used in the correct cell, weeks 1-11 countif() needs to equal 2, and week 12 needs to equal 1 for every team/ream

The goal seeking objective is to target the sum of all the week numbers which should equal 144*24 = 3456

When I am running the solver ([OpenSolver](https://opensolver.org/)) It is returning errors with all the different linear and non-linear solvers.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with your model (difficult to tell without having a look at the spreadsheet or not being a mind reader).

This is a problem that really requires that we first develop a mathematical model before we start coding or typing. Here is my mathematical model for this problem:

[image]

I use the definition:

```
game(t1,t2,r) = 1 if team t1 plays against team t2 in round r (only for t1<t2 to prevent double counting)
              = 0 otherwise
```

Not completely trivial, but this can be implemented with any MIP solver: all constraints are linear. When I tried this, my results look like:

```
----     24 VARIABLE game.L  schedule for teams

                   round1      round2      round3      round4      round5      round6      round7      round8

team1 .team15                                   1
team1 .team16                                               1
team1 .team17                                                                                   1
team1 .team18                                                           1
team1 .team19           1
team1 .team20                                                                                               1
team1 .team22                                                                       1
team1 .team24                       1
team2 .team12                                                                                   1
team2 .team15                                               1
team2 .team16                                                                                               1
team2 .team19                       1
team2 .team20                                                           1
team2 .team21                                                                       1
team2 .team23           1
team2 .team24                                   1
team3 .team12           1
team3 .team13                                                                       1
team3 .team14                                                                                               1
team3 .team15                       1
team3 .team16                                                                                   1
team3 .team21                                                           1
team3 .team23                                   1
team3 .team24                                               1
team4 .team10                                                                                               1
team4 .team14                                                                                   1
team4 .team15           1
team4 .team16                                                           1
team4 .team18                       1
team4 .team21                                               1
team4 .team22                                   1
team4 .team23                                                                       1
team5 .team11                                               1
team5 .team15                                                           1
team5 .team16                       1
team5 .team18                                                                                   1
team5 .team19                                                                                               1
team5 .team20                                                                       1
team5 .team21                                   1
team5 .team22           1
team6 .team9                                    1
team6 .team10                                                           1
team6 .team11           1
team6 .team16                                                                       1
team6 .team17                                                                                               1
team6 .team20                                                                                   1
team6 .team22                                               1
team6 .team23                       1
team7 .team9                        1
team7 .team10                                                                                   1
team7 .team12                                                           1
team7 .team14                                                                       1
team7 .team16                                   1
team7 .team19                                               1
team7 .team21                                                                                               1
team7 .team24           1
team8 .team9                                                1
team8 .team11                                   1
team8 .team12                                                                       1
team8 .team13                                                                                               1
team8 .team14                       1
team8 .team16           1
team8 .team19                                                           1
team8 .team22                                                                                   1
team9 .team18                                                                       1
team9 .team20           1
team9 .team21                                                                                   1
team9 .team22                                                           1
team9 .team23                                                                                               1
team10.team17           1
team10.team20                                   1
team10.team21                       1
team10.team23                                               1
team10.team24                                                                       1
team11.team17                       1
team11.team18                                                                                               1
team11.team19                                                                       1
team11.team23                                                                                   1
team11.team24                                                           1
team12.team17                                   1
team12.team18                                               1
team12.team22                       1
team12.team24                                                                                               1
team13.team17                                               1
team13.team18           1
team13.team19                                   1
team13.team20                       1
team13.team23                                                           1
team13.team24                                                                                   1
team14.team17                                                           1
team14.team18                                   1
team14.team20                                               1
team14.team21           1
team15.team17                                                                       1
team15.team19                                                                                   1
team15.team22                                                                                               1

            +      round9     round10     round11     round12     round13     round14     round15     round16

team1 .team9                                                                                                1
team1 .team10                                                                                   1
team1 .team11                                                                       1
team1 .team12                                                           1
team1 .team13                                               1
team1 .team14                                   1
team1 .team21                       1
team1 .team23           1
team2 .team9                                                                                    1
team2 .team10                                               1
team2 .team11                                                           1
team2 .team13                       1
team2 .team14           1
team2 .team17                                                                                               1
team2 .team18                                                                       1
team2 .team22                                   1
team3 .team9                                                                        1
team3 .team10                                   1
team3 .team11                                                                                               1
team3 .team17                                                           1
team3 .team18                                                                                   1
team3 .team19                       1
team3 .team20           1
team3 .team22                                               1
team4 .team9                                                            1
team4 .team11           1
team4 .team12                       1
team4 .team13                                                                       1
team4 .team17                                                                                   1
team4 .team19                                                                                               1
team4 .team20                                   1
team4 .team24                                               1
team5 .team9                                                1
team5 .team10                                                           1
team5 .team12                                   1
team5 .team13                                                                                               1
team5 .team14                                                                                   1
team5 .team17                                                                       1
team5 .team23                       1
team5 .team24           1
team6 .team12           1
team6 .team13                                                                                   1
team6 .team14                       1
team6 .team15                                                                       1
team6 .team18                                               1
team6 .team19                                                           1
team6 .team21                                                                                               1
team6 .team24                                   1
team7 .team11                                               1
team7 .team13                                   1
team7 .team15                                                                                               1
team7 .team17                       1
team7 .team18           1
team7 .team20                                                           1
team7 .team22                                                                                   1
team7 .team23                                                                       1
team8 .team10                       1
team8 .team15           1
team8 .team17                                               1
team8 .team18                                   1
team8 .team20                                                                       1
team8 .team21                                                                                   1
team8 .team23                                                                                               1
team8 .team24                                                           1
team9 .team17                                   1
team9 .team19           1
team9 .team24                       1
team10.team18                                                                                               1
team10.team19                                                                       1
team10.team22           1
team11.team20                                                                                   1
team11.team21                                   1
team11.team22                       1
team12.team19                                                                                   1
team12.team20                                                                                               1
team12.team21                                                                       1
team12.team23                                               1
team13.team21           1
team13.team22                                                           1
team14.team19                                               1
team14.team22                                                                                               1
team14.team23                                                           1
team14.team24                                                                       1
team15.team18                                                           1
team15.team20                       1
team15.team21                                               1
team15.team23                                   1
team15.team24                                                                                   1
team16.team17           1
team16.team18                       1
team16.team19                                   1
team16.team20                                               1
team16.team21                                                           1
team16.team22                                                                       1
team16.team23                                                                                   1
team16.team24                                                                                               1

            +     round17     round18     round19     round20     round21     round22     round23

team1 .team2                                                                                    1
team1 .team3                                                                        1
team1 .team4                                                            1
team1 .team5                                                1
team1 .team6                                    1
team1 .team7                        1
team1 .team8            1
team2 .team3                                                            1
team2 .team4                                                                        1
team2 .team5                                    1
team2 .team6                                                1
team2 .team7            1
team2 .team8                        1
team3 .team4                                                                                    1
team3 .team5                        1
team3 .team6            1
team3 .team7                                                1
team3 .team8                                    1
team4 .team5            1
team4 .team6                        1
team4 .team7                                    1
team4 .team8                                                1
team5 .team6                                                                                    1
team5 .team7                                                                        1
team5 .team8                                                            1
team6 .team7                                                            1
team6 .team8                                                                        1
team7 .team8                                                                                    1
team9 .team10                                                                                   1
team9 .team11                                                                       1
team9 .team12                                                           1
team9 .team13                                               1
team9 .team14                                   1
team9 .team15                       1
team9 .team16           1
team10.team11                                                           1
team10.team12                                                                       1
team10.team13                                   1
team10.team14                                               1
team10.team15           1
team10.team16                       1
team11.team12                                                                                   1
team11.team13                       1
team11.team14           1
team11.team15                                               1
team11.team16                                   1
team12.team13           1
team12.team14                       1
team12.team15                                   1
team12.team16                                               1
team13.team14                                                                                   1
team13.team15                                                                       1
team13.team16                                                           1
team14.team15                                                           1
team14.team16                                                                       1
team15.team16                                                                                   1
team17.team18                                                                                   1
team17.team19                                                                       1
team17.team20                                                           1
team17.team21                                               1
team17.team22                                   1
team17.team23                       1
team17.team24           1
team18.team19                                                           1
team18.team20                                                                       1
team18.team21                                   1
team18.team22                                               1
team18.team23           1
team18.team24                       1
team19.team20                                                                                   1
team19.team21                       1
team19.team22           1
team19.team23                                               1
team19.team24                                   1
team20.team21           1
team20.team22                       1
team20.team23                                   1
team20.team24                                               1
team21.team22                                                                                   1
team21.team23                                                                       1
team21.team24                                                           1
team22.team23                                                           1
team22.team24                                                                       1
team23.team24                                                                                   1
```

Of course, the solution is not unique. The model solved in 0.2 seconds.